# Dual Channel Memory Mode

Tags: memory

I have 2 RAM DIMM, and in CPU-Z under SPD,
it showed me different values for something
and I would like to know if I am able to run Dual Channel mode or not.
Pictures of CPU-Z

CPU-Z slot 1: [image: Click Here]
CPU-Z slot 3: [image: Click Here]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** The JEDEC profile #4 for slot 1 is identical as profile #5 for slot 2.

Comment: But values are not the same, is there a way to check it using a software?

Comment: @Mr.LegalBoy Look at the respective profiles I mentioned in the answer.